# PHP Mail Function and Header Redirects Not Working Together

Tags: php, email

The following code is used to send a email to users who's emails were provided by the user.

```
$from_whom_header = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, 'noreply@test.com'); //setting a static from field

$from_whom = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['your_email']); // this is used to pass the email of the person sending the email into the subject line and body of email

$headers = 'From:'.$from_whom_header; //passing in static address stated above 

$subject_email = $from_whom.'mentioned you in their latest post!';

$body_email = '//email text...';


if(@mail($to, $subject_email, $body_email, $headers))
{

     echo ' emailing...';                                                                                   

}

else
{

    $oh_noes_2 = '<div class="error">'.'error sending mail'.'</div>';

} 


header('Location: email_success.php');
```

For whatever reason, the header command is not working. I am using object buffering (ob_start() etc.) and I tried placing this script right under the ob start tags with still no result.

My question then becomes is there some confusion in PHP between the $header used in the mail function and the header  command used to redirect?

For some context, this script comes after some validation logic, and I put the echo 'emailing...' test in there for debugging and even when the header command was nested in there and the echo proved that the mail command was working, it still did not want to redirect.

Comment: Is email_success.php in the same directory with that file?

Comment: add this to the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, run the script, does it displays any errors ?

Comment: It sure does! header already sent. I can't seem to find where the header is already declared though. The page before it that also uses headers has an ob_flush command. I guess if we are really nit picking I didn't use an exit command. Could that throw it off?

Comment: See my answer, it will make it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After error logging I found that something was miss-configured in session.save_path string of PHP.ini. I was able to edit it and the problem resolved. The issue was found after an error was tossed at the bottom of the page saying the path was bad and was unable to open the session variables.

Moving forward to anyone who might see this question later on, if session variables are not setting, on the great advice of the people who commented, make sure the following is true.

- Session start is present at the top of all php doc before ANYTHING is outputted. It is a good idea to call OB_start() as well.
- check your session IDs are the same. this is done by simply echoing the session_id() variable at the top of your doc.
- place the error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); string at the top of your doc and search for errors. If you get open command errors, follow the error to the line in PHP.ini and change the directory. In my case I had to use a predefined folder on the host server that handles temp variables.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of your code:

```
if(@mail($to, $subject_email, $body_email, $headers))
{

/* Don't output anything before using header, otherwise you'll get errors.  
   echo 'emailing...';*/ 

header('Location: email_success.php');       
}

else
{

    $oh_noes_2 = '<div class="error">'.'error sending mail'.'</div>';

}
```

[From the manual...](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: Still having a little bit of trouble. A further examination of the error string shows that the header is already defined on the line where I put the header command (if that makes sense...) In other words, it is saying it can't modify the header because it is already defined on the line where I declare it. That seems sort of counter intuitive if you ask me.

Comment: Your code is outputting something before the headers.Cleanup any blank lines, spaces, etc.

Comment: What if someone wants to send the mail and then redirect to another page? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yes,  it's possible.